# How do I print the sum of an array's elements?

Tags: java

I've written a program, where the user gives input on how many elements they want their array to have. However, I am unable to print the sum of those elements.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class sumOfArrayValues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter array size here: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        int[] myArray = new int[size];

        Random rand = new Random();
        int limit = 101;

        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = rand.nextInt(limit);
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();

        }

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i : myArray) {
            sum += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the array elements is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

If there are any other tips to make my code less verbose, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: You're not adding the values of the elements, just 1 for each. That'll count them, not add them up.

Comment: sum += 1; what do you want to add? the value contained by each cell/bucket? or just adding 1 for each cell/bucket in the array

Comment: @office.aizaz After someone's input, I realize what I had done wrong. I was wanting to add up the value of the array's elements...example; {10, 12, 35}, the program should output (10+12+35) 57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add `i` to the sum if you want the sum of all the elements. Right now `sum` reflects the size of `myArray` because you only add 1 for every element in the array.

```
for (int i : myArray) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Comment: It worked! I switched the 1 with i and my array elements are adding up. So, thank you!

Comment: @esker-luminous consider accepting the answer if the problem has been fixed. Lets other people know that the question has been answered :)

Answer (score 4):

> If there are any other tips to make my code less verbose, please don't hesitate to let me know.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter number of elements to sum: ");
int size = input.nextInt();

Random r  = new Random();
// generate a stream of `size` values between 0 and 100 inclusive
// and sum them
int sum = r.ints(size,0,101).sum();

System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Streams tend to make brief code

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( 0 , 101 ).limit( arraySize ).toArray()
```

… and …

```
IntStream.of( randomInts ).sum()
```

## Streams

You asked:

> any other tips to make my code less verbose

Streams are another way to write brief code. The [`IntStream`](https://file:///Users/basil_dot_work/Tools/Java%20API/Java%2018/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()) class is for a stream of integer values.

[`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://file:///Users/basil_dot_work/Tools/Java%20API/Java%2018/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) is a random-number generator that is automatically instantiated one per thread. You can use the class even if not spawning threads. The class has many handy methods. Here we use the `ints` method to generate a stream of random numbers. We then collect those into an array of `int` values.

```
int[] randomInts = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( 0 , 101 ).limit(7).toArray();
```

We can dump those to console.

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( randomInts )   );
```

> [41, 54, 54, 20, 91, 80, 50]

And we can [calculate the sum](https://file:///Users/basil_dot_work/Tools/Java%20API/Java%2018/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum()) of those `int` values by creating another `IntStream`.

```
int sum = IntStream.of( randomInts ).sum();
```

> sum = 390

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://import%20java.util.Arrays;%20import%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;%20import%20java.util.stream.IntStream;).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the pointers! However, I will have to revisit these once I have gained some expertise in Java, as most of what you have said is incoherent to me. I appreciate you taking the time though :-)